# Replace page document.getElementById(ID Name); with count up timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, counter, greasemonkey

I have a script that reloads a page once in a while randomly between a time set, and i want to add a timer since the page loaded.

A timer like HH(24):MM(60):SS(60), so i know exactly how many minutes/seconds have elapsed since the page reload.

Preferably i want to replace a ElementById with the timer, duckduckgo as an example, replacing the logo with a visible timer on the page:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Timer Duck
// @namespace   Timer Duck
// @description Simple counter
// @include     https://duckduckgo.com/
// @version     1.0.0
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==


$(document).ready(function() {     

//Replace 'logo-wrap--home' with a visible counter formated '24(hours):60(minutes):60(seconds)'

});
```

I just don't know how to actually show it on the page.

Comment: Oh, it looks like you need a programmer. Please make sure you read [ask] before posting your next question. We love to help, but you need to show a *decent attempt* at coding it yourself first. Welcome to [so]!

Comment: `document.getElementById()` will return, at most, a single element that has an `id` matching the parameter you passed. Example `document.getElementById('my-element')` will return a single element with `id="my-element"`. Figuring out how much time has passed since the page has loaded has NOTHING to do with `document.getElementById()`. I'll add answer below to show how many seconds have passed since page load.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you need to do a few things to make this work.

You need to initiate your counter variable:

```
var seconds_passed = 0;
```

You need a function to check when the page loads:

```
$('window').on('load', function(){
  // other code goes in here
});
```

You need a function that continuously runs so you can count the time:

```
function timer() {
  setTimeout(function() {
      // Here you are incrementing the amount of seconds passed by 1.
      // This works because the setTimeout function is running every second(we pass as 1000, for 1000 milliseconds).
      seconds_passed++;
      // log to the console how many seconds have passed.
      console.log(seconds_passed);
      // Here we run the timer function again. This is a recursive function. It calls itself.
      timer();
  }, 1000);
}
```

All together, it looks like this:

```
var seconds_passed = 0;

$('window').on('load', function(){
  timer();
}); 

function timer() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    seconds_passed++;  
    console.log(seconds_passed);
    timer();
  }, 1000);
}
```

**Explanation:** When the page loads, it runs the timer function. The timer function will: add 1 to the variable `seconds_passed`, log `seconds_passed` to the console, and will finally call itself to run again.

Comment: Main question updated, sorry if i didn't described correctly, i'm not that good at coding.

Comment: Ok, so add a new element. Let's say h1 so you don't miss it. Give that h1  the attribute `id="seconds-passed"`. Inside the timer function. Add `$('#seconds-passed").html(seconds_passed);`. You are passing the variable `seconds_passed` in as the HTML for the element with `id="seconds-passed"`.